# Best practices for Post-Redirect-Get (PRG) with MVC in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, post-redirect-get

Is there any best practice for PRG pattern with MVC? 
In this tutorial:
http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post 
the proposed solution requires 4 actions: 
**Create_Item** (POST) => "resets" the form and redirects to Display_Item
**Display_Item** (GET) => shows the form (with temp data and errors if exists) 
**Store_Item** (POST) => try to save data to DB, if errors, save errors and redirect to Display_Item, if success redirect to Display_Stored
**Display_Stored** (GET) => shows the item created or a success message, tec. 

Now, I think that to have the first action with POST is a problem, because we can't start the form with a link. Using GET in *Create_Item* seems a better option.

And also, we can do the same with 3 actions (using the same action for Create_Item and Display_Item, but with an extra *flag* for reseting the form, for example:
http://www.example.com/controller/Create_Item/?reset=1 

And also we can do the same with just 2 actions, because we can use an if inside *Create_Item* for checking if the request is GET or POST (so we are combining Display_Item with Store_Item).

And also we can do the same with just 1 action, because we can have an extra flag (in the URL query or in a session) for showing the results instead of the form:
GET http://www.example.com/controller/Create_Item/?reset=1  => shows a new form and redirects to the next URL 
GET http://www.example.com/controller/Create_Item/ => shows a form with temp data and errors if exists 
POST http://www.example.com/controller/Create_Item/ => save errors in temp, or data in DB (and set a session flag for success) and redirects to above URL or next URL 
GET http://www.example.com/controller/Create_Item/ => if $_SESSION['success'] show results

Personally I like the idea of having 4 actions, but I don't have any real advantage over the others options. But I don't feel secure choosing my design without a real criteria.
Does somebody know the **PROS** and **CONS** of each design (if any)? 

For example, I see the 4 actions cleaner, but if we want to change how the temp data is saved, we need to change it in 4 places.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is to `GET` a blank form, modify the contents of the form, then `POST` that to the server, which then sends a redirect to another page which is a `GET`, perhaps to a page saying `Form submitted successfully.`. (Get->)Post->Redirect->Get

The first action is not really `POST`. That's the end result of completing a form and submitting it. The guide is more about what to do after that `POST`, as if you do not do a redirect, then the user is left on a page saying `Form submitted successfully` where they could just hit F5 and do another `POST`. With that redirect however, they're on that results page via a safe `GET` which will not result in a double post.

As for the implementation, you should have each be its own action on the server side. This is inline with the MVC / RESTful implementation.

- GET /url?action=new -> Call new_form() method to render a new form
- POST /url?action=create -> Call create_form() method to save and redirect to /url?action=show&id=1234
- GET /url?action=show&id=1234 -> Call show_form() method to display the result
- POST /url?action=save&id=1234 -> Call save_form() method to save and redirect

You could use 3 actions here instead if you wanted to have the 2nd action call `save`. Most REST/CRUD conventions use the 4, but the choice is yours. The benefits are the same as going the REST/MVC route in the first place.

See these resources as well:

- [RESTful web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services)
- [This](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/restful-rails-part-i/) covers typical conventions for RESTful controllers. It covers rails, but still applies to PHP as well if you're wanting to go the REST route.

Comment: yes, I understand PRG, but I'm asking about the implementation (with MVC in PHP). We can use 4 actions, 3, 2, 1, and I can't see clearly if there's an advantage of one of those over the others.

Comment: Updated to hopefully clarify. Using 4 is more conventional and clearly states what you're doing so there's no confusion in the code implementation between rendering an existing form vs rendering a new form vs saving a form vs creating a form. Best to split it all up.