# Implementing PHP and MySQL without refresh alerts

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am somewhat new to PHP and MySQL, and have just setup a basic login + register system (it took me forever to be satisfied with my error messages!).

I have noticed a major annoyance with my code. When a user logs in, I run

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

after the validating and comparing username and password with database entries.

A bit further down in the code, I have something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'])
{
    //show that user has logged in
}
```

Upon page refresh, I get a popup, saying that **"Firefox must send information that will repeat any action that was performed earlier.**"

I am pretty sure that this is caused by the accessing of the database, even though that shouldn't happen with my setup: I only connect to the database once the user has clicked the "login" button. This button is hidden when the user is logged in. Why, then, is this message appearing? Can I prevent it without making drastic structural changes or even using a different language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: I don't really understand that article.

Comment: [This article](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Post-Redirect-Get.aspx) explains it better. More sources: [1](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) [2](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/get-redirect-after-post) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930734/best-practices-for-post-redirect-get-prg-with-mvc-in-php)

Comment: Looks good, gonna read through it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with your server-side language. What happens is that the user submitted a form and the browser sent a POST request. If you display such a website in your browser and press "refresh", Firefox will not just redisplay the page, but actually want to sent the complete POST request again.

Because that request may have been to transfer $1000 to your ex-wife (read: have side effects), the browser asks for confirmation.

A possible solution would be to follow a successful login with a redirect to another page, so that the most recent HTTP request is a GET, not a POST request.

Comment: So I guess the solution to this is not to put the login on the homepage, but to transfer it to a separate page, and then redirect to home.php after login? At least that's how Youtube does it :)

Comment: The target page can be your very same PHP script or whatever, the point is just that you have to make the browser perform a new HTTP request. Setting a `Location` header like @Ashley says is a good idea, or you could have a meta-refresh hack. The server-side design is entirely up to you.

Comment: Ok, but don't the headers have to go at the beginning of the PHP code?

Comment: By the way, don't forget to make a new session ID upon successful login using [session_regenerate_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) to thwart session fixation attacks.

Comment: The headers have to come first *logically*, before any other output. But there are many ways to structure your code to achieve that. (Worst case there's *output buffering*.)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. What exactly does session_regenerate_id() do?

Comment: It makes a new session ID and send the appropriate cookie. If you didn't do that and the client already sent you their own session ID in a cookie, you would just use that same one. Now the client could have been manipulated into using a cookie known to the attacker, who can then steal the session. By creating a new ID, you make sure that nobody knows the session ID until the valid login.

Comment: How about session.cookie_httponly? I just watched [a video](http://youtu.be/6uhsN7eJQ4A) on that subject.

Comment: What about it? That's a server configuration setting that enables session handling only if it can be done via cookies. It effectively disables the insecure session handling via URL parameter.

Comment: Oh, is that not the sort of "hack" that session_regenerate_id() is meant to prevent?

Comment: No. This is unrelated. But if you fall back to non-cookie, URL-based session IDs, even regenerating can't save you :-)

Comment: This is getting way off topic; you should probably get a good book on web application foundations or look on the internet for good tutorials on setting up secure login systems. Basically, a URL is much easier to leak (and doesn't have any origin restrictions) than a cookie; think about the referrer sent to embedded third-party images etc...

Comment: @user805556 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2894/discussion-between-kerrek-sb-and-user805556)

Answer (score 1):

It's because it resubmits the entered data, to solve it simply redirect the user after login. This must go before any output (so no HTML or echo/print statements).

```
header('Location: profile.php'); //Or wherever you want them to go
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior of webpage. If you refresh, the browser notice that you have already sent this information via Post form and warn you to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

> I am pretty sure that this is caused by the accessing of the database,

I am pretty sure that this is caused by form submission. Firefox will warn you that you are about to re-submit a form, which has already been submitted once.